# Copy the adress of array B to an index in array A

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, strcat

Quick one... i want to copy the adress of an array 'B' to an index in array 'A', something like "strcat":

```
char *strcatme (char s1[] ,char s2[]){

    int i=0;

    while (s1[i]!='\0') i++;

    s1[i] = &s2;

    return s1;
}
```

but it doens't work, any tip for a noob? ;)

Comment: The address is not the data.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The elements of `s1` are characters, not pointers.

Comment: The type for `s1` needs to be `char *s1[]` since `s2` is an array and is treated like a pointer.

Comment: s1[i] = s2; (i don't know if you mean this -> also doesn't work xP )

Comment: When you say 'strcat' you mean you want to copy the string from s2 into s1 starting at `s1[i]`? You'll need another loop to copy it character by character, including the \0 terminator.

Comment: Explain what exactly what you want to do and what you expect the result to be, preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: `s2` is a local variable, so `&s2` is a pointer to a local variable. So even if `s1` had the correct type, you'd be returning a pointer to a variable that is destroyed when the function ends.

Comment: By the way, saying "it doens't [sic] work" gives the reader no idea as to what the problem is. You must include error messages and a description of both the desired behavior and the behavior you are seeing if you want reasonably good assistance.

Comment: If you're looking for a shortcut to copying the contents of `s2` into `s1`, there isn't one. These are not linked lists, they're separate blocks of memory.

Comment: As "Rup" was assuming, i want to concat the string 1 with string 2 without going loop char by char...
now i assume that isn't possible...

Comment: Well you could use an existing function to do that, e.g. strcpy or memcpy, but since you're writing your own strcat I guess you don't want to do use library functions.

Comment: the output:

String 1: lol
String 2: lol ----->
lol�

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to copy multiple characters. How many? You'll need a second loop, to find the `\0` at the end of `s2`.

Free tip: if you copy not just the character, but also that last `\0` from `s2` to `s1` as well, then `s1` will remain zero-terminated.

Free tip 2: Make sure to test it with an empty string as well. Concatenating the empty string should leave the original unchanged.

Comment: i was trying to concat without going char by char... i guess my question is solved, i can't... ty for your time m8

Comment: @M0b1os: as the comments note, either you go char-by-char or you have `strcat` do that for you. Someone has to, that follows from the desired end result where multiple characters have been copied.